# How to get only first duplicated expression with different value with regex?

Tags: html, regex, wordpress, web-scraping

I'm scraping data from automotive site to customers website with Octolook Scrapes plugin for Wordpress. Everything works fine with two exceptions! The probčem is that I'm getting duplicated expressions with different value. But only first duplicated expression has right value.

example:

```
<div class="AdData AdDataZero Data8">
<div class="AdDataLeft">First registration: 5 / 2012 </p>                                      
<div class="AdData AdDataZero Data5">
<div class="AdDataLeft">First registration: 5 / 2010 </p>
<div class="AdData">
<div class="AdDataLeft">Produstion year: 2012 </p>
<div class="AdData AdDataZero DataZero1">
<div class="AdDataLeft">Mileage: 187356 </p>
<div class="AdData AdDataZero DataZero2">
<div class="AdDataLeft">Mileage: 156356 </p>                                                  
<div class="AdData">
<div class="AdDataLeft">Technical inspection: 5/2020 </p>
```

The problem is with "**First registration**" and "**Mileage**"! Both are duplicated with some strange reason, but only first value of "First registration" and "Milage" are correct. And now I'm wondering hot to get only first expression with correct value?

Comment: Regex isn't the right tool for parsing HTML, even if it could handle this requirement.

Comment: I know that is not a best tool! I'm also new to this and I don't know why do I have to get dislikes If I'm asking for help... obviously I need help, not criticism! Scrapes only has option to find and replace. And my logical explanation is that to trz to fix that with regex. If any of you guys can help me with solution, I would be very thankfull.

Comment: You should at least state the logic for which of the duplicates is the right one.

Comment: Yep, I agree... but here lies the problem hot to reach that logic :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preg_match will always match the first occurrence:

```
$html = '<div class="AdDataLeft">First registration: 5 / 2012 </p>' .
  '<div class="AdData AdDataZero Data5">' . 
  '<div class="AdDataLeft">First registration: 5 / 2010 </p>';

preg_match('/First registration: (\d+ \/ \d+)/', $html, $m);

echo $m[1];
```